# Accordion animation is really slow in iOS Framework7-vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, accordion, html-framework-7

I am building both android and iOS app with Framework7-vue.
The Android app works perfectly, but the iOS app gives me troubles.

The user will be given the option to view a popup, this popup will have an accordion inside.
The animation in iOS is terribly slow and it looks awful.
I've been trying some stuff and googled a bit but no success.

Bellow you will find my implementation of the app.js and a snippet containing the popup.
I will be happy to hear suggestions, thank you.

**app.js**

```
const questions =  {
    questionOne:'Does the subject have a high CCA?',
    options: {
        yes:'Yes',
        no:'No'
    },
    selected:{
      yes: {
        questionTwo: 'High PTH and yes to high CCA',
        options: [
          'PTH > 80pmol/L',
          'PTH < 80pmol but > 50pmol/L and increasing',
          'PTH < 50 but higher than base line'
        ]
      },
      no: {
        questionTwo: 'PTH > 80pmol/L',
        options: [
          'Refer for surgical parathyroidectomy',
          'Start Cinacalcet if parathyroidectomy is'
        ]
      }
    }
}
//  this.$$ - this.Dom7;

Vue.use(Framework7Vue);

// Init Page Components
Vue.component('page-education', {
  template: '#page-education'
});
Vue.component('page-mbddef', {
  template: '#page-mbddef'
});
Vue.component('page-ckdmbdeffects', {
  template: '#page-ckdmbdeffects'
});
Vue.component('page-algorithms', {
  template: '#page-algorithms'
});
Vue.component('page-highpth', {
  template: '#page-highpth'
});
Vue.component('page-dietary', {
  template: '#page-dietary'
});



// Handle device ready event
// Note: You may want to check out the vue-cordova package on npm for cordova specific handling with vue - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cordova
document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
  console.log("DEVICE IS READY!");    
}, false)

// Init App

// var $$ = dom7;
// console.log($$);
// var $$ = this.Dom7;
// console.log($$);
const mainApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    popupOpened: false,
    navBarShowing: true,
    showingGreenCard: false,
    currQuestion: questions.questionOne,
    currOptCount: 2,
    currOptions: questions.options,
    showing: false,
    isShowing: true,
    icon:       "<i class='far fa-file-alt'></i>",
    homeIcon:   "<i id='sidemenu-icon' class='fas fa-home'></i>",
    pencilIcon: "<i id='sidemenu-icon' class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i>",
    healthIcon: "<i id='sidemenu-icon' class='fas fa-plus'></i>",
    algIcon:    "<i id='sidemenu-icon' class='fas fa-align-justify'></i>",
    dietIcon:   "<i id='sidemenu-icon' class='fas fa-utensils'></i>",
    clipIcon:   "<i id='sidemenu-icon' class='far fa-clipboard'></i>",
    linkIcon:   "<i id='sidemenu-icon' class='fas fa-link'></i>"
  },
  progress: {
    value: 10
  },
  on: {
    pageInit: function(){
      console.log('page');
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setInlineProgress: function(value) {
      this.value = value;
      const self = this;
      const app = self.$f7;
      app.setProgressbar('#demo-inline-progressbar', this.value);
    },
    toHomeScreen: function() {
      this.$f7.getCurrentView().router.back({ pageName: 'home-page', force: true, refreshPrevious: true});
      this.$f7.closePanel();
    },
    shouldShow: function() {
      this.showing = true;
    },
    generateQuestion: function(answer){
       this.currQuestion = questions.selected.yes.questionTwo;
       this.optionsOne = 'Yes';
       this.optionTwo = 'No';
       this.shouldShow();
    },
    showPopUp: function(e) {
     this.showingGreenCard = true;
    },
    closePopUp: function(){
      this.showingGreenCard = false;
    },
  },
  on:{

  },
  // Init Framework7 by passing parameters here
  framework7: {
    root: '#app',
    /* Uncomment to enable Material theme: */
    material: true,
    routes: [
      {
        path:'/',
        name: 'home'
      }
      ,
      {
        path: '/education/',
        component: 'page-education'
      },
      {
        path: '/ckdmbddef/',
        component: 'page-mbddef'
      },
      {
        path: '/ckdmbdeffects/',
        component: 'page-ckdmbdeffects'
      },
      {
        path: '/algorithms/',
        component: 'page-algorithms',
      },
      {
        path: '/highpth/',
        component: 'page-highpth'
      },
      {
        path: '/dietary/',
        component: 'page-dietary'
      },
      {
        path: '/form/',
        component: 'page-form'
      },
      {
        path: '/dynamic-route/blog/:blogId/post/:postId/',
        component: 'page-dynamic-routing'
      }
    ],
  }
});
```

**Here is the popup snippet:**

```
 <div class="popup-card-four" v-if="mainApp.showingGreenCard">
                <p class="popup-text">Suitable low phosphate foods</p>
                <i id="close-icon" @click="mainApp.closePopUp()" class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
                <f7-list class="main-acc-list" accordion-list>
                    <f7-list-item id="acc-one-title" accordion-item title="Lower phosphate diary">
                      <f7-accordion-content class="table-wrapper">
                        <f7-block >
                            <table class="main-table">
                                <tr class="table-underline">
                                  <td class="popup-inner">Milk</td>
                                  <td class="popup-inner">Rice or milk</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="popup-inner">Cheese</td>
                                  <td class="popup-inner">Cottage Cheese</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td></td>
                                  <td class="popup-inner">Cream cheese</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td></td>
                                  <td class="popup-inner">Quark</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="table-underline">
                                  <td></td>
                                  <td class="popup-inner">Ricotta</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="popup-inner">Cream</td>
                                  <td class="popup-inner">Single, double, whipping,</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td></td>
                                  <td class="popup-inner">pouring, clotted,</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td></td>
                                  <td class="popup-inner">Marscapone</td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                        </f7-block>
                      </f7-accordion-content>
                    </f7-list-item>
                    <f7-list-item id="acc-one-title" accordion-item title="Lower phosphate diary">
                      <f7-accordion-content>
                        <f7-list>
                          <f7-list-item title="Item 1"></f7-list-item>
                          <f7-list-item title="Item 2"></f7-list-item>
                          <f7-list-item title="Item 3"></f7-list-item>
                          <f7-list-item title="Item 4"></f7-list-item>
                        </f7-list>
                      </f7-accordion-content>
                    </f7-list-item>
                    <f7-list-item id="acc-one-title" accordion-item title="Lower phosphate diary">
                      <f7-accordion-content>
                        <f7-block>
                          <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean elementum id neque nec commodo. Sed vel justo at turpis laoreet pellentesque quis sed lorem. Integer semper arcu nibh, non mollis arcu tempor vel. Sed pharetra tortor vitae est rhoncus, vel congue dui sollicitudin. Donec eu arcu dignissim felis viverra blandit suscipit eget ipsum.
                          </p>
                        </f7-block>
                      </f7-accordion-content>
                    </f7-list-item>
                  </f7-list>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by removing the framework7-vue component for accordion and replacing it with the standart framework7 html accordion component.

It seems that iOS does not like framework7-vue components.
Hope this will be helpful to someone.
Cheers.